# Get text, not value from selected SELECT element with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have defined my select element as (Jade syntax)

```
    select(ng-model="chosenProject.value" id="chosenProject"  ng-options="c.value as c.name for c in selectItems")
```

where selectItems is an array of objects with "value" and "name" fields.

I would like, if possible, to keep this notation as it is very compact. However, 
ng-model field ends up with only value of selected item. I however need both value and name of it.
How do I proceed in order to obtain the text (aka "c.name" in code above)  also?

Comment: Can't set it to the entire object?

Comment: How exactly I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `c.value as` part. This will set the value of select to the whole `c` object.

```
select(ng-model="chosenProject" id="chosenProject"  ng-options="c.name for c in selectItems")
```

Now you `chosenProject` will be set to the whole JSON of the element selected, so you can get both the value and the name.